# Import python module in nsclient script

Tags: python, nagios, nrpe

I'm trying to writing a sample python prgram for nsclient to get cpu utilization and then return the status to nagios server.

Below code is giving Import Error : ImportError: No module named psutil
I dont know how to import external library in nagios python

```
import psutil
import sys

cpu_percent = psutil.cpu_percent()
print(cpu_percent)
if cpu_percent > 10:
    print("CPU Utilization is really high")
    sys.exit(2)
elif cpu_percent > 5:
    print("CPU is going high")
    sys.exit(1)
elif cpu_percent > 0:
    print("System is working fine")
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    sys.exit(4)
```

Comment: Include the command entry in the nsclient config file.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put **#!/link/to/your/python/interpreter** at the top of the file so that it's recognized as a python script. For e.g. on some linux machines, this works **#!/usr/bin/python.**. You could type **which python** to get the path to the interpreter. Hope this helps :)

PS: Make sure to restart the NSClient++ service if you make changes to the **nsclient.ini** or the **check_commands.ini** file